# Can I add new environment variable to docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

There are ways to pass the environment variable declared in dockerfile using the `docker run` command using `--env` or `-e` options.

E.g. Lets say you are using MAC or linux, then you can define a shell variable like below:

`export MyEnvVar=SomeValue`

And then pass this value to an environment variable that was defined inside your dockerfile.

`docker run --name "MyContainerName" -e MyEnvVar Container_Image_Name`
And for this to work you must have a statement in the dockerfile like below:

`ENV MyEnvVar=${MyEnvVar}`

However, I do not want to define any variable inside dockerfile but add a new environment key/value while creating a container instance using `docker run` or some other way.

So is there a way to add a new environment variable using `docker run` or by some other means in to a docker container without declaring that environment variable in dockerfile?

Comment: To add to @Matt, you can also use `--env-file` flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an environment variable at run time doesn't require the `ENV` to be defined in the `Dockerfile`

```
$ docker run -e TEST=OHYEAH busybox sh -c 'echo $TEST'
OHYEAH
```

As [@djmm187](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2920736/djmm187) mentioned, `--env-file` will work the same too.